# How to load dependencies(MS-SQLServer Win-Service) before windows-services 

Tags: windows-services

help me with an issue please.
My windows service depended on MS SQL server, and It has to load some information on start up, but it is starts before MS SQL and stops with an exception. I set dependency with a "sc" tool (sc config MyService depend= MSSQL) but my service still does not start on system load. MS SQL added as depednecy, I can see it in dependency tab of service properties and sc qc MyService command but my service still does not start. Can anyone help? My system is Win7, MS SQL Server 2008 R2, my service runs under local system and MS SQL is network service. Thanks a lot.

P.S. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is the service set to start automatically, or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use dependencies

[How to delay loading of specific services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888)

or use "Automatic (Delayed Start)" option for your service Please read

[WS2008: Startup Processes and Delayed Automatic Start](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx)

or

You can manage this through programming logic, that if **resource is unavailable**

repetitively check for it and when its available proceed for normal operation,

and you can intimate Service Client though appropriate response

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thanks for a help. Most probably I'll use delayed services, code solution (like thread sleep) in my case is worst possible way. Service dependency is perfect way, but in my case it does not work :( and I have an idea why (maybe I'm not right). My service really starts after SQL server OnStart, but before some of other necessary services, so it crushes when I try load something from the DB at start up.